# Re-using a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a custom control with a `TabControl` and a `DataGridView` that I've added to a `WinForm` with the name "DGV" and wrote 2 methods on that control that are like this:

```
public void addTabs(string str)
{
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(str, str);
    tabControl1.TabPages[str].Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
}

public void fillDataGrid(string Name, long Size1, long Size2)
{
    int cols = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[cols];
    row.Cells["FileName"].Value = Name;
    row.Cells["Size"].Value = Size1 + " Kb";
    row.Cells["CompressedSize"].Value = Size2 + " Kb";
    row.Cells["Format"].Value = "Zip";
}
```

So then in my Form I'm doing this:

```
foreach (FileInfo f in dInfo.GetFiles("*.zip"))
{
    string n = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name);
    Dgv.addTabs(n);

    string totalPath = Tx.Text + "\\" + f;

    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(totalPath))
    {
        foreach (ZipEntry zp in zip)
        {
            Dgv.fillDataGrid(zp.FileName, zp.CompressedSize, zp.UncompressedSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Doing this only a tabPage will have all the data in the `DataGridView`. Creating new `DataGridViews` inside the loop and then add them to a `TabControl` will do the trick, but the problem is that I want to manage the selected items in the `DataGridView` cells, so, I need to find a way to add the loop data properly to the corresponding tabPage `DataGridView`. Hope someone can help me to find a way to reuse the `DataGridView` per tab or finding a better way to do what I want.

Comment: Why do you need to reuse one dgv?

Comment: Because I want to manage the selected cells in a dgv that will be added in many tabPages of a tabControl with different data, and if I programatically create a new dgv per tab I won't be able to manage the selected cells on another method.

Comment: OK,what I'm imagining now is one set of data with different tab pages, each page has a datagrid view with different columns displaying different fields about the same data set?

Comment: I'm searching in a loop for zip files and then creating tabs of my custom control (That is composed by a tabcontrol and a dgv) for each file found and then filling the datagrid in other loop with the content of the zip but since I cannot reuse the datagrid, all the zip content is being added just into one tab dgv.

Comment: See my answer, a datagrid view has a data source property that you can use to bind your data. Use your loops to populate a dataset. Then your dgviews can show/edit what u want them to between one common set.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DataSet class and add your data to that. Bind your datagrid views to one dataset and use any combination of dgvs to edit, select, modify, and pass selected values etc